# Как в Python Stdout вывести в переменную?

Tags: python

Транслировать весь вывод в файл я могут так:

```
import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('submission.txt', 'w')
print ("Hello, World!")
```

И тогда "Hello, World!" будет в файле submission.txt, а не выведется на печать.

А как весь вывод (всё из stdout) отправить в какую-нибудь переменную?

Comment: вывод чего вам надо перехватывать? вы будете запускать внешнюю программу из Python скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример из документации по [contextlib.redirect_stdout()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    help(pow)
s = f.getvalue()
```

> Context manager for temporarily redirecting sys.stdout to another file
>   or file-like object.
>
> This tool adds flexibility to existing functions or classes whose
>   output is hardwired to stdout.
>
> For example, the output of help() normally is sent to sys.stdout. You
>   can capture that output in a string by redirecting the output to an
>   io.StringIO object:

**Внимание:** функция `contextlib.redirect_stdout()` была добавлена в Python 3.4

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо, кажется то что нужено!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, во 2 питоне эта радость так же хорошо работает как и в 3?

Comment: @АлексейЗадойный,  эта функция была добавлена в Python 3.4 :(

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. приведённый выше совет не работает для 2 питона, есть гибрид стартового кода и приведённого, который можно переключать для работы в 2/3 питонах:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO #python 2
#from io import StringIO #python3
import sys

print(0)

old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()

print(1)

sys.stdout = old_stdout

print(2)
print(mystdout.getvalue())
```